# How to sort the resultant values of my loop?

Tags: c++

This is a program that reads a textfile and tells the user the number of rows and the maximum number of words in a line. There are two primary commands, numrows filename and numcols filename. The first one works for me but the numcols filename command is supposed to give the user the maximum numbers of words in a line in the file. For example, if the text file contains two lines and line 1 has 2 words and line 2 has 5 words, when numcols filename is entered, the output should be 5.

Currently, my loop finds the number of words in each line but I'm not sure how to use those values and find the largest one to cout when the command is entered. Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

```
    #include <iostream>                                                       
    #include <fstream>  
    #include <istream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;               

    void prompt()
    {
        cout << " >> ";
    }

    int main() 
    {
        string fname, line, strn, input;                                                         

        ifstream ifs; // input file stream         
        istringstream ss1,ss2;                                 
        int i;        
        cout << " ** USAGE ** " << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << " numrows <filename> - displays the number of lines " << endl;
        cout << " numcols <filename> - displays the number of columns" << endl;   
        cout << " quit/exit/bye - exit the program" << endl; 
        cout << " " << endl;  
        prompt();

        while (getline(cin, strn)){
        ss1.str (strn);

        ss1 >> input;
        ss1 >> fname;

        ifs.open(fname.c_str()); 

        if (ifs.fail()) {                                                       
            cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open file " << fname << endl;   
            ifs.clear();     

        } else {  
            if (strn == "numrows " + fname) {
                int number_of_lines = 0;
                string line;                                                                          
                while (getline(ifs, line))      
                    ++number_of_lines;
                cout << number_of_lines << endl;
                prompt();

            }   else if (strn == "numcols " + fname) {
                string line1;
                while ( getline(ifs,line1) )
                {                                       
                    int words=0; 
                    istringstream is(line1); 
                    while(is >> line1) 
                    ++words; 

                    cout << max << endl;                            
            }                                                                                       
                prompt();

            }   else if (strn == "quit" || strn == "exit" || strn == "bye"){
                cout << "TESTING " << endl;
                return (0);

            }  else {
                cout << "Invalid Command! Retry.." << endl;
                prompt();
            }   
        }                     
        ifs.close();                      
        }
        return 0;                                                                   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a new variable `max_words` which holds the the maximum number of words in the lines you have processed so far. Read a new line, count the words and compare it with `max_words`, if the word count is larger,  assign the value to the word count, otherwise, leave the value as it is.

```
int max_words = 0;
while (getline(ifs, line1)) {
    int words = 0;
    istringstream is(line1);
    while (is >> line1) { ++words; }
    if (words > max_words) {
         max_words = words;
    }
}
cout << max_words;
```

You can initialize max_words with 0 and get the correct value as there will be no word count < 0.

Comment: Hey man, it worked. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. Just one more question..The program also has a quit/exit/bye command, which only works after the first input prompt.. the invalid command catch also doesn't work on the first input when the program starts. I'm not sure how I can fix that.

Comment: When you type quit the variable `input` will be "quit" and `fname` an empty string. That means you are calling ifs.open() with an empty string as a filename.

Comment: So what should I do. Sorry I am confused.